# BigQuery selecting one row of a repeated column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So let's say I have a table with these columns and vlaues:

```
 ------------- ----------
| customer_id | order_id |
|-------------|----------|
|      14     |    3     |
|      17     |    9     |
|      17     |   12     |
|      17     |   33     |
|      44     |    1     |
 ------------------------
```

That is 2 columns, where one can get repeated values (`customer_id`) and the other doesn't get repeated values (`order_id`).

How can I query the table so that I get unique `customer_id` values? When `customer_id` is repeated I want to grab the row that has the smallest `order_id`. So I'm assuming an `ORDER BY` statement is needed for that.

If I use `GROUP BY` to group the columns I'll get a query like:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT customer_id, order_id FROM table
GROUP BY customer_id, order_id;
```

which still shows all `customer_id` rows.
I tired using `DISTINCT`, but that resulted the same values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 14 customer_id, 3 order_id UNION ALL
  SELECT 17, 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 17, 12 UNION ALL
  SELECT 17, 33 UNION ALL
  SELECT 44, 1 
)
SELECT customer_id, MIN(order_id) AS order_id
FROM `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY customer_id
-- ORDER BY customer_id
```

with result as

```
Row customer_id order_id     
1   14          3    
2   17          9    
3   44          1
```